# Ordering by month & year in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL, sorry!
I need this query to return the data ordered by month and year, but I'm not getting it and I can't adjust it.

Here we go!

```
select 
CASE
WHEN datepart(month, created_at) = '1' THEN 'January'
WHEN datepart(month, created_at) = '2' THEN 'February'
WHEN datepart(month, created_at) = '3' THEN 'March'
WHEN datepart(month, created_at) = '4' THEN 'April'
WHEN datepart(month, created_at) = '5' THEN 'May'
WHEN datepart(month, created_at) = '6' THEN 'June'
WHEN datepart(month, created_at) = '7' THEN 'July'
WHEN datepart(month, created_at) = '8' THEN 'August'
WHEN datepart(month, created_at) = '9' THEN 'September'
WHEN datepart(month, created_at) = '10' THEN 'October'
WHEN datepart(month, created_at) = '11' THEN 'November'
WHEN datepart(month, created_at) = '12' THEN 'December'
end as Month,
datepart(year, created_at) as Year, 
count (distinct id) as Countd
from table
where
created_at >  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '12 months'
Group by Month, Year
Order by Month, Year desc
```

Thanks for all support! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
to_char(created_at, 'Month') as Month,
date_part('year', created_at) as Year, 
count (distinct id) as Countd
from table
where
created_at >  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '12 months'
Group by date_part('month', created_at), date_part('year', created_at)
Order by date_part('month', created_at), date_part('year', created_at) desc
```